# How to work with a bunch of buttons (Show/Hide) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to learn how work with a group of buttons without specifying Ids for the following task:

Hide and Show Div body, Div header stay show.

I was able to make one with this code:

```
function hide(){
document.getElementById('here').classList.toggle('hide')
}
```

but Hiding/Showing each individually was prove to be more difficult.

The sample here:  [Show/Hide Div Body](https://tools4you.neocities.org/helpPlease.html)

I know there is something like:

```
Let btns = document.querySelectorAll('buttons);
Let tables = document.getElementsByClassName('here');

function HideShow(){
//What do I put here???????  :)
}
```

Note: I can't use ids, because I want to add so many divs to make it dynamic.

**UPDATE**::::::     **UPDATE**::::::    **UPDATE**::::::
I had to do it the old fashion way, with ids!! and IF/ELSE, not cool!  :(

```
let tables = document.getElementsByClassName('here');

var theParent = document.querySelector('#theDude');
theParent.addEventListener('click', doSomeThing, false);

function doSomeThing(e){
if( e.target!==e.currentTarget){
var clickedItem = e.target.id;

if(clickedItem=='one'){
tables[0].classList.toggle('hide')
}else if(clickedItem=='two'){
tables[1].classList.toggle('hide')
}else if(clickedItem=='three'){
tables[2].classList.toggle('hide')
}else if(clickedItem=='four'){
tables[3].classList.toggle('hide')
}
e.stopPropagation();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your node lists into your Hide and show, and then iterate over them

```
Let btns = document.querySelectorAll('buttons);
Let tables = document.getElementsByClassName('here');

function HideShow(elemArray){ // note: I've added an elemArray parameter here
//What do I put here???????  :)
  elemArray.forEach(elemArray, function(elem) {
    //with each element, toggle hide or show
    //elem.classList...
  }
}
```

Comment: By "node lists" you mean the btns, right?...

       let btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
       let tables = document.getElementsByClassName('here');


       function HideShow(btns ){ 
        btns .forEach(btns , function(elem) {
        tables.classList.toggle('hide');
         })
         };

Comment: The btns or the tables

Comment: I wish I can understand you better, I've tried what you said but it's not working... :(

Answer (score 0):

HTML: `<button onclick="hideThisButton(this);">Button</button>`

JS: let btns = document.querySelectorAll('buttons);
    let tables = document.getElementsByClassName('here');

```
// use this to hide all the buttons
function HideShow(){
 for(let i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
     // you can access the index i over here
     // change the logic to hide or show specific buttons
     btns[i].classList.toggle('hide');
  }
}

   // use this method for hiding a specific button on click
   function hideThisButton(event)
   {
    var btn = event.target;
    btn.classList.toggle('hide');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Your code is hiding all the buttons, so I changed it to hide the tables, but know it hide all of them, not just the one you click on. :(

Comment: Edited the answer, please check the function hideThisButton(event).

Comment: Hi, If you see my example I'm trying to hide/show each Div table independently not the button. I tried your code but it's not working! :(